# How to use find, ls commands to display file names based on entries in an array?

Tags: linux, bash, sh, ksh

I have an array, that contain the wildcards/filenames tha may be present in a directory. How can I display the files in a directory, whose names matches with names in the array. By the way, if possible, without using for loop.

Ex:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name $FILE_ARR[@]

ls $FILE_ARR[@]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is to use curly braces when accessing arrays:

```
ls ${file_array[@]}
```

For `find`, it's a bit more complex, as `-name` only accepts one argument, not multiple.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name $(echo ${file_array[@]}| sed 's/ / -o -name /g')
```

Note that it doesn't work if any path contains whitespace.

Comment: Thank you. This find syntax is working. the ls syntax is listing entries from array as is if file doesn't exist.

Comment: It works for me. How do you assign the values to the array, what are the wildcards, what are the file names?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the filename pattern don't contain white space:

```
 echo ${arr[@]}|fmt -w 1|xargs -i -r -n 1 find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name
```

The `fmt` breaks the input into individual lines and `xargs` distributes the pattern to the individual find commands.

Still, I consider an explicit loop easier to read and more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

For `find` here is a solution that deals with arbitrary file-names and other options for find

```
#!/bin/bash

# dummy -name patterns for find
file_array=(
  *.jpg
  *.png
)

# construct find options array
find_options=( \( )
for ((i=0; i<${#file_array}; i++)); do
  [[ $i -gt 0 ]] && find_options+=( -o )
  find_options+=( -name "${file_array[$i]}" )
done
find_options+=( \) )

find . -maxdepth 1 "${find_options[@]}"
```